# single quote inside double quotes in shell script

Tags: shell, sed, quotes

I would need to replace in a file strings like `"'a"` with strings like `'a`.
In practice, I need to remove the double quotes.

I was thinking to use sed to do it, but I could not find a solution til now: I guess I am making some syntax errors because of the quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just need to remove all double quote characters from the file then you can use `tr` with the `-d` option:

```
$ cat test.txt
this is a test "'a"
something "else"
doesn't touch single 'quotes'

$ cat test.txt | tr -d '"'
this is a test 'a
something else
doesn't touch single 'quotes'
```

**Update:**

If you want to replace the specific instance of `"'a"` with `'a` then you can use `sed`:

```
sed "s|\"'a\"|'a|g" test.txt
this is a test 'a
something "else"
doesn't touch single 'quotes'
```

However, I suspect that you are after something more general than just replacing quote markes around an `a` character. This `sed` command will replace any instance of `"'anything"` with `'anyhting`:

```
sed "s|\"'\([^\"]\+\)\"|'\\1|g" test.txt
this is a test 'a
something "else"
doesn't touch single 'quotes'
```

Comment: Thank you, but in this way i remove all the double quotes of the file. I want to remove only the one wrapping 'a. I want to keep the others

Comment: yes, exactly. The output I would like to have should be:          this is a test 'a
something "else"
doesn't touch single 'quotes'

Comment: yes, I actually needed something more general. I needed to remove the single quote around any vowel. But I have just realized that in my file the quote are only before vowels, so your solution still works great. Thanks a lot!

Comment: To match only vowels you can use `"s|\"'\([aeiou]\+\)\"|'\\1|g"`

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work for me

```
echo '"a"' | sed "s/\"a\"/\'a/"
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/"\('\''[^"]*\)"/\1/g' file
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use :

```
perl -pe 's/\042//g' your_file
```

042 is octal value of double quotes.

tested below:

```
> cat temp
"'a"
> cat temp | perl -pe 's/\042//g'
'a
>
```